# Fluid Simulation: Inflow is stretching to the edge of domain when baked

Tags: cycles-render-engine, fluid-simulation

Here you can see an animation of my fluid sim. The inflow is that small black circle.

[image]

For some reason, the fluid flows in from the space between the inflow and one edge of the domain...

[image]

Here are a couple other views showing the domain and inflow windows.

[image]

[image]

How might I go about fixing this?

Additional notes:

- I get "No active UV layer found in the object" when I bake via the render panel (not when I bake via the physics panel). I don't know if this is significant or not.
- Object scales are all at 1.0x, 1.0y, 1.0z.

Comment: weird. Have you checked if any transform needs to be applied? Can you share the .blend?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The normals of the inflow object are inverted. Flip or recalculate them.

Comment: Took me a while to remember how to do fluid sims but you appear to be correct!

Comment: This saved me so much frustration, thank you!