# Fluid domain stretched to boundary after baked

Tags: normals, fluid-simulation

This is actually a duplicate of [this SO question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/39973/fluid-simulation-inflow-is-stretching-to-the-edge-of-domain-when-baked), but since my problem is still not solved I thought this is the correct way to find a solution for my problem:

I have a fluid domain (cube) and a fluid object (uv sphere) inside it (guess that is the standard). Without having changed anything big my fluid object or rather just the fluid is being stretched to one side of the domain boundary. Take a look at the picture:

[image: problemsss]

In the other post the accepted answer is
"The normals of the inflow object are inverted. Flip or recalculate them."
which I tried but that did not help. Unfortunately I am a super beginner and after hours of trying don't know how I could solve this myself. Thanks.

Here is the [.blend](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/1364/) file.

Comment: Welcome in BSE. I think you should post your [.blend file](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your inflow sphere has a negative scale.

[image: inflow negative scale]
Use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> to apply the scale,
[image: apply scale]
[image: applied scale]
The scale is applied but we can see the normals have changed (reversed because of the negative scaling).
[image: normals in]
To fix them, enter edit mode with <kbd>Tab</kbd>, select all with <kbd>A</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd>
[image: normals out]
Now you can bake your bath :
[image: bake fixed]

Comment: Oh my god thank you. But I wonder how this happened in the first place? Thanks again!

Comment: Thank you for explaining the part about the normals getting reversed because of scaling. As a beginner, I would never have realized this could be the reason for this problem. And now I know how to prevent it too!